# control speed of settimeout within Ajax call

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, settimeout

I am am trying to control the speed of a canvas object via a slider. The problem is that the canvas is reading data from an ajax call and i can't seem to access the time out variable to change the speed via a slider on the page.

I have removed all code that is not working.
I have it back to the last working version without the slider value with hard coded values for the settimeout speed.

```
$.ajax({

url: "/static/Data/test.txt",
dataType: "text",
cache: false,
async: true,
success: function (data) {
    var arr =   data.split(/,/g).slice(0);
    function drawShape(x , y,colour){
        context.strokeRect(p + gridX,p,gridX,gridY);
        context.fillStyle = colour;
        context.fillRect(p + gridX * x,p+ gridY * y,gridX,gridY);
    }

    for(let i=0; i<arr.length -2; i+=2){
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            x1 = arr[i];
            y1 = arr[i+1];

            context.clearRect(0, 0, 650, 650);

            drawBoard();
            if(grid_type == "grid_standard") {
                drawShape(5, 0, 'green');
                drawShape(5, 1, 'red');
                drawShape(4, 3, 'red');
                drawShape(4, 4, 'red');
                drawShape(2, 2, 'red');
                drawShape(2, 3, 'red');
                drawShape(y1, x1, 'yellow');
            }
            if(grid_type == "grid_cliff") {
                drawShape(5, 5, 'green');
                drawShape(4, 5, 'red');
                drawShape(3, 5, 'red');
                drawShape(2, 5, 'red');
                drawShape(1, 5, 'red');
                drawShape(y1, x1, 'yellow');
            }
            //  $("body").append("Pos: " + x1 + "  "+y1);
        }, i * 50);

    }


    //console.log($.unique(position));
    // $("#div1").text(data);
}
```

});

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the current timeout and create a new timeout if you want to change the duration. It is often better to use reguestAnimationFrame https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame and use time difference you get from it combined with the speed you set to find how much to change in each frame.

If you want to use setTimeout, you can do something like `var timeout = window.setTimeout(rest of your code`
and when changing value `clearinterval(timeout);` and recreate the timeout